# In Eagle, red area(i guess top layer) doesn't appear when i click on ratsnets tool

Tags: eaglecad

After autorouter was done, i clicked on ratsnets tool and i expected top layer area to be seen, however nothing appears.

This is my project.

[image]

I expected to see top layer like in this picture after i clicked on ratsnets.
[image]

Comment: Have you named the polygon with the net you want it to cover?

Comment: Also make sure you have clearance between the edge of the poly and the edge of the board.

Comment: Yes, i named both blue and red layer GND. but i drew the polygon exactly over the edge of the board. Should i change it?

Comment: I can't remember how Eagle clearance rules work, but I would give it at least half a millimeter, if not more, between the pour and the edge of the board.

Comment: And I'm not talking about naming layers, I'm talking about naming the polygon itself using the "Name" tool. Whiskeyjack's answer covers this.

Comment: The polygon won't fill if it's name doesn't match one in the schematic. Do you have a net named GND in the schematic?

Comment: Another option, do you accidentally have two overlapping polygons with different names (e.g. if you accidentally copied the polygon directly over itself and renamed one of them).

Comment: I have many nets named GND in the schematic.

Comment: For the latter, i have just two polygons that overlap but they have the same name "GND"

Comment: Could you upload your eagle file somewhere? I'd like to take a look

Comment: for brd
https://www.dropbox.com/s/15f0yvmyquhrb9s/ADXL345_Breakout.brd?dl=0

for sch
https://www.dropbox.com/s/utokm8y9g8tasso/ADXL345_Breakout.sch?dl=0

Comment: @ucha thanks. See my answer as to why it isn't filling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sees that while the other answers correctly say how to set up the polygon to be on the correct net and how to display it using the `ratsnest` tool, they all miss a vital setting. To be fair I wouldn't have figured it either had I not seen your board file.

The issue is with the `isolate` setting on the polygons:

[image: Isolate Bad]

You currently have an `isolate` value of 12. In the upper left of the Eagle window it displays the units to be `mm`. What this means is that there must be **12mm** of clearance between the polygon and any copper from another net, hole, or the board outline. As a result the polygon cannot fill because no area of the board which meets this requirement.

If you reduce the isolate setting down to something like 0.4mm, then it does fill correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to make a ground pour. Let's say you have ground named as GND.

Right click on the dotted polygon. Click on Name. Edit the Name to GND. Hit OK. Hit Ratsnest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn on display of filled polygons.  I don't remember the exact syntax, but "HELP RAT" should bring up the documentation page that mentions it.

Comment: In my experience the polygon fills were shown by default. Has this changed with the newer versions of Eagle?

Comment: @der: The are on by default in my setup, but I don't remember whether that's something I deliberately set a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Press the button on the side toolbar with the description of 'Ratsnest'. This will fill up the polygon. If you have the default setup its at the bottom end of the side bar (on the left).

Comment: I did many times, the polygon is not being filled.

Comment: First make sure you are on the copper layer. If you are check the filling option, make sure it is on solid. You will have to find the option yourself as it varies with version. Mine is located under the top toolbar near the width setting. I am using version 7.1.0.

Comment: I don't know how to be on the copper layer. i clicked right, selected properties and selected solid among hatched, cutout and solid. mine is 7.4.0
I might set the circuit again, because once it was done.

Comment: By copper layer I mean the top layer. You change that from the top toolbar.

Comment: Okey. I saw how to choose top layer. I was in top layer before.